Exporting hair curves and cards for UE5: Coloring fur based on image texture?
The TL;DR is that I can create texture-based color-inheriting alembics + hair cards when working with a new, clean fur curve system in the Blender > UE5 pipeline. I am unable to recreate this successfully, however, when converting hair particles to fur curves, and I suspect it has to do with certain Attributes that are easily accessible in Curves that are not so accessible in a Particle system.
The reason I must find a way to go from particles to curves/hair cards is that for my current project I am bound to using a preexisting set of assets that implement Particles in order to create the needed hair cards.
I hope you'll bear with me as I detail my whole process of discovery; I want to make it clear what have and have not tried.
With a new scene, I create Fur Curves on the default cube. These are exported using the Groom Export addon to an alembic file:

I convert them to meshes using Hair Tool (I'm sure this isn't the only way, but it's simple and clean) and export these as an FBX in order to use as custom hair cards:

In UE5, I create a material that uses the Hair Attributes node and the desired texture (1). Importing the alembic file and setting up the system like so (and using Cards instead of Strands), I get fur with the desired pattern (2):

It works wonderfully for this default cube, but when I move on to the more complicated thing I'm trying to get (a cat), I can only get a single solid color, even when all settings are identical (1). The only difference I can see is that the curves that make up the cat are not a single system: There are eight separate parts to the whole. So I tried to isolate just the tail (only tail curves + only tail cards), but in vain (2):

Testing further: I imported just the cat geometry, and created a new, from-scratch fur curve system and replicated the first curves-to-alembic process. It turns out that this works perfectly, and that there's some major difference between exporting native fur curve alembics and going from particles > fur curves.
Most notably, I learned from this tutorial (https://youtu.be/AnzLNdYvt34) that there is a list of Attributes that are by default connected to default curves, to which list you can add Color and Radius, and a custom Roughness Attribute:

When converting particles to curves, these attributes do not carry over. I assume they exist in some form on the particles, though, because when a material with an image texture is applied to the particle system, it inherits the per-vertex/face colors of that texture:

Also, whereas before with native hair curves I was able to just create out of thin air the "roughness" Attribute (as per the tutorial earlier mentioned), it does not look like the necessary surface_uv_coordinate, UVMap, and the others can be added manually with any expectation of a successful connection, even though in UE they are listed as present when importing the alembic curves:

It's at this point that I'm at a loss as to where to look. I don't know where that information is located in the Particle system to begin with, much less where to find where it goes when Particles are converted to Curves.
Is there something I'm missing, or is what I'm trying to do wholly impossible?
Thank you!
